# Удаление повторяющегося элемента из массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Получая строку "abxcxxdxxxef" необходимо получить строку "abcdef". Написал код, который удаляет x только если x не идет подряд. То есть на выходе получаем строку "abcxdxef".

Понимаю почему это происходит, но не понимаю как это исправить. Буду благодарен за **объяснение** (в приоритете) как это исправить и/или исправленную часть кода.

```
for (place = 0; str[place] != '\0'; place++)
{
    if (str[place] == 'x')
        for (int i = place; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
            str[i] = str[i + 1];
}
```

Comment: Не полностью ясно что нужно сделать. Удалить все `x` из строки?

Comment: @entithat да, необходимо удалить все

Comment: @AnT то, что не совсем корректно не спорю.) но факт остается фактом. ввожу abxcxxdxxxef и получаю abcxdxef. находя "ненужный" элемент код сдвигает все элементы строки влево и сокращает выводимую строку. проблема, что если элемент повторяется то влево сдвигается как раз таки ненужный элемент.

Comment: Отлаживать пробовали? Подсказка: что происходит при удалении символа `x`, после которого еще раз идет `x`?

Comment: а последовательность символов после удаления важна?

Comment: В заголовке вопроса фигурирует слово "повторяющегося". В чем заключается необходимость этого слова? Почему "повторяющегося"?
 Если вам на вход дано `abxc`, то надо удалять `x` или не надо?

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не записывать все в отдельную строку ?

```
string str="abxcxxdxxxef";
string str2="";
for (int place = 0; str[place] != '\0'; place++)
{
  if (str[place] != 'x')
     str2+=str[place];
}
cout<<"\n"<<str2;
```

Comment: а если вы не знаете какие символы повторяются ?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan задача стояла именно для `х` , вам нужно все повторяющиеся символы удалить ?или мб из всех повторяющихся оставить только одну ? и тп, укажите точно

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char str[] = "abxcxxdxxxef";
    size_t len = sizeof(str);

    size_t writePtr = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    for(;i < len; ++i) {
        if(str[i] != 'x') {
            str[writePtr] = str[i];
            ++writePtr;
        }
    }

    cout << str << endl;
}
```

Храним индекс символа для записи и если текущий символ не равен `x` копируем его по индексу для записи и увеличиваем индекс.

Comment: @entithat, действительно, в один цикл тут не обойтись(

Answer (score 1):

Пример удаления нескольких повторяющихся.

*В цикле проходим по каждому символу строки, проверяем на существование такого же. Если существует, то останавливаем проверку и идём дальше. Если же не нашли такой же, то в выходную строку добавляем символ **(который уникален).***

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string s = "abxcxxdxxxef", out;

    bool repeat;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {  
        repeat = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
            if (i != j && s[i] == s[j]) {
                repeat = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!repeat) {
            out += s[i];        
        }
    }

    cout << out << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Тесты:**

```
1. Ввод: abxcxxdxxxef  Вывод: abcdef
2. Ввод: helloworld    Вывод: hewrd
3. Ввод: 11258348      Вывод: 2534
4. Ввод: 1122333       Вывод: пустая строка
```

Comment: Можно вместо вложенных циклов использовать битовую строку (32 байта), которую сначала обнуляем, а потом, используя код символа как индекс бита, смотрим был ли уже такой символ. Кстати, если символы надо именно удалять из исходной строки, то out (как `char *`) можно совместить с памятью в `s` (а в конце сделать resize)

Comment: Что мешает? 32 байта это массив из 4 int. Делите код символа на 32 -- получаете индекс в этом массиве. Остаток от деления -- номер бита. Сдвигаете 1 влево на номер бита -- получаете маску. Операцией `&` проверяете установлен ли уже бит в массиве. Операцией `|=` устанавливаете его. Все очень просто

Comment: @avp, можно еще использовать `bitset` с этой же целью. Но ваш вариант мне нравится даже больше, наследие C живет.

Comment: @Ternvein, не только живет, но и [побеждает](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/)

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно заранее знать какая строка будет и какие символы повторяются, а на языке C++ можно написать например так

```
#include <iostream>
using std::string;
string& binop(string& s, char c)
{
   if (s.back() != c) s += c;
   else
       s.erase(--s.end());
   return s;
}

int main()
{
    // тест
    string str = "prkkkkkkogrbbbbbbam         C++";
    str = std::accumulate(str.begin(), str.end(), string(), binop) + '?';
    std::cout << str;   //выдаст:  "program C?"
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если задача просто состоит в удалении всех `'x'` из строки, то ваш исходный подход будет прекрасно это делать. Надо просто помнить, что индекс `place` следует инкрементировать не безусловно, как у вас, а только если текущий элемент строки не был равен `'x'`

```
for (int place = 0; str[place] != '\0'; )
  if (str[place] == 'x')
    for (int i = place; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
      str[i] = str[i + 1];
  else
    ++place;
```

Однако все можно сделать одним проходом и одним циклом

```
int dst = 0;

for (int src = 0; str[src] != '\0'; ++src)
  if (str[src] != 'x')
    str[dst++] = str[src];

str[dst] = '\0';
```